# Pydub concatenate mp3 in a directory

Tags: python, concatenation, pydub

I would like to concatenate all .mp3s in one directory with pydub. 
The files are numbered consecutively file0.mp3, file1.mp3 etc.

this code from the example code:

```
playlist_songs = [AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file) for mp3_file in glob("*.mp3")]
```

gives me all files and now I would like to concatenate, like in pseudocode:

```
for i in playlist_songs:
    append i to finalfile
```

Is there a way to achieve this or am I approaching it wrong ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can start with an empty sound like so:

```
combined = AudioSegment.empty()
for song in playlist_songs:
    combined += song

combined.export("/path/to/output.mp3", format="mp3")
```

or if you'd like to get a little fancy and use 5 second crossfades you'll have to pop the first song off the list

```
combined = playlist_songs[0]

for song in playlist_songs[1:]:
    combined = combined.append(song, crossfade=5000)

combined.export("/path/to/output.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just sum as elements of a Python list:

```
sum(playlist_songs)
```