# How to pause text during speaking in gTTS

Tags: python, gtts

This is my code that generates a audio file of what is written in variable text.

**I want to take a pause between Hello and world. How can I do that ?**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

text = "Hello **pause** World"
language = "en"

myobj = gTTS(text = text, lang = language, slow = False)
myobj.save("test.mp3")
#os.system("test.mp3")
```

I will be very thankful to you for answering my question.

Comment: How long do you want the pause to be?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a full stop between the words adds some pause:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
from playsound import playsound

text = "Hello . World"
language = "en"

myobj = gTTS(text = text, lang = language, slow = False)
myobj.save("test.mp3")
playsound("test.mp3")
#os.system("test.mp3")
```

Do you want the pause to be longer or be able to manipulate the duration?

If so, check out the following thread: [Adding a pause in Google-text-to-speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819936/adding-a-pause-in-google-text-to-speech)

Comment: The pause should be longer like 5 or 10 seconds.